# How do I call a method when a public property changes in Flex 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

If I have a .mxml file that has a method in it and a public property, can I have the method execute whenever the property changes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:HBox xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[           
            [Bindable]public var myProperty:MyType;

            private function myMethod(myProperty):void
            {
                // Method to run every time myProperty changes
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
</mx:HBox>
```

In another .mxml file I have added this .mxml file like so:

```
<viewComponents:MyViewComponent myProperty="{myVariable}" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `get` and `set` accessor methods. More details is [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/learn/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f36.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fcb).

In you case it is something like:

```
private var _myProperty:MyType;

public function set myProperty(value:MyType):void
{
    _myProperty = value;
    // he best way is to place myMethod body here
    myMethod(_myProperty);
}

[Bindable]
public function get myProperty():MyType
{
    return _myProperty;
}
```

Comment: @Brian L I voted to reject the edit.  Making the full class bindable would work, but I would consider it a bad practice in many situations.  Many properties on any given class most likely don't need to be made Bindable; so why add in code to make them so?

Comment: @www.Flextras.com That's understandable, I suppose you're right.  It does make sense that the _best practice_ would be marking only the needed fields `[Bindable]`.  Though, I did want to point out to the asker (@DaveC) the option of binding the entire class.

Answer (score 7):

Since no one said this yet, I'll propose a second approach.

Every property in the Flex Framework will dispatch a property named something like *property*Changed. where *property* is the name of the property to be changed.  Said properties are implemented using get set methods as others have mentioned.  Something like this:

```
private var _myProperty:MyType;

[Bindable(myPropertyChanged)]
public function get myProperty():MyType
{
    return _myProperty;
}
public function set myProperty(value:MyType):void
{
    _myProperty = value;
   dispatchEvent(new Event('myPropertyChanged'));
}
```

These event name specified in the Bindable metadata is used for binding purposes.  So, instead of calling your method inside the set, you could listen for this myPropertyChanged event:

```
component.addEventListener('myPropertyChanged',onMyPropertyChanged)
```

And elsewhere in the code:

```
protected function onMyPropertyChanged(event:Event):void{
 // do other processing
}
```

This may be overkill for what you're trying to accomplish; or not.  Since you didn't go into specifics on what you were trying to accomplish, I'm not sure.

If your new functionality relates to the Flex Component LifeCycle in some manner, such as changing the display or the size you should be performing your changes in the lifecycle ethods; not in your set method.  Something like this:

```
private var _myProperty:MyType;
private var _myPropertyChanged:Boolean = false
[Bindable('myPropertyChanged')]
public function get myProperty():MyType
{
    return _myProperty;
}
public function set myProperty(value:MyType):void
{
    _myProperty = value;
   _myPropertyChanged = true;
   invalidateProperties();
   invalidateDisplayList();
   invalidateSize()
   invalidateSkinState(); // spark comps only
   dispatchEvent(new Event('myPropertyChanged'));
}
```

The invalidate methods will force the component lifecycle method to rerun during the next render event and you can use code like this in the relevant method:

```
if(_myPropertyChanged == true){
  _myPropertyChanged = false;
  // do other processing
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you place event name of `[Bindable]` rag in quotes the following way `[Bindable("myPropertyChanged")]`?

Comment: And to tell the true you don't need to dispatch event manually in your case. Leaving `[Bindable]` tag alone without parameters will produce `"propertyChange"` event automatically (by `mxmlc` compiler). But anyway there is a lot of cases where manual event dispatching can be very useful. And of course the class which dispatches event manually should be inherited from `EventDispatcher` or implement `IEventDispatcher`.

Comment: @constantiner Inside the Flex Framework the 'propertyChange' events are manually dispatched; so I have always done it that way in my my own code.  I'm not sure if MXML components do different things than an AS only components.  But, you are correct to dispatch an event the class must extend EventDispatcher or implement IEventDispatcher.  All Flex UI Components do so.

Comment: `mxmlc` always generates some code for ActionScript classes with `[Bindable]` declarations even if they are not inherited from `EventDispatcher`. You can see it using `-keep-generated-actionscript=true`.

Answer (score 4):

This is how I would do it.  Create a setter function that calls the method you propose:

```
var _mystatus:Number = 0;

function set mystatus(val:Number):void
{
_mystatus = val;
alertfunction();
}

function get mystatus():Number
{
return _mystatus;
}
```